# How to drag icon by image not by point modify?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2

I use Modify object and `Translate` object for moving point layer:

```
 this.source = new VectorSource();
    this.vector = new VectorLayer({
      source: this.source,
      zIndex: 900,
      style: new Style({
        fill: new Fill({
          color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)",
        }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: "#ffcc33",
          width: 2,
        }),
        image: new Icon({
          anchorXUnits: "fraction",
          anchorYUnits: "pixels",
          crossOrigin: "anonymous",
          anchor: [0.5, 145],
          scale: 0.5,
          color: "#c5a368",
          src: "./assets/images/point.svg",
        }),
      }),
    });

    this.modify = new Modify({ source: this.source });
    this.mapService.map.addInteraction(this.modify);
    this.mapService.map.addLayer(this.vector);

    const translate = new Translate({
      features: new Collection(this.source.getFeatures()),
    });

    translate.on("translateend", (e) => {
      let lonLat = toLonLat(e.coordinate);
    });

   this.draw = new Draw({
      source: this.source,
      type,
      stopClick: true,
      style: getStyleFunction(),
    });
```

Problem is I can move pointer only by bottom of icon.

[image]

How to move pointer by whole image?

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/modify-icon.html  Set the `htiDetection` option to true, or to the layer.

Comment: Does not work: `this.modify = new Modify({ source: this.source, hitDetection: this.vector });` 

Also is it possible to remove blue circle on the bottom of pointer?

Comment: It moves the map

Comment: Referring to properties of `this` in Modify should work as long as it is not in a callback (where you will need bind or arrow functions).  The blue circle is the default modify style, use an empty array or void function as style to remove it https://codesandbox.io/s/modify-icon-forked-7xuymc?file=/main.js